# Save output of multiple commands to the same file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, files, command

For example whoami and date. I can do this that way

```
whoami>/home/user/folder/file
date>>/home/user/folder/file
```

But i'm sure it can be done in one line without typing path two times. I have tried using

```
|
```

but always first command is ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a subshell

```
(whoami; date) > ~user/directory/file
```

Answer (score 3):

You could accomplish this with a single redirection using echo/printf along with command substitution:

```
printf '%s\n' "$(whoami)" "$(date)" > /home/user/folder/file
```

IMO this is not a good solution, it is not very readable/manageable...especially if more commands are added.

In order to prevent having to type the path multiple times you could just save it in a variable:

```
file=/home/user/folder/file
whoami>"$file"
date>>"$file"
```

But this requires multiple redirections as well.

If you wanted to write a long script or subset of commands and wanted to perform a single redirection for them you could use command grouping:

```
{
whoami
date
} > /home/user/folder/file
```

Or on one line:

```
{whoami;date;} > /home/user/folder/file
```